# Looping the statement

Tags: java

I would like to loop the statement below so that for individual filename it outputs, I want to check if it exists in database. Can someone show how I can go about looping (for loop) this individually?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File folder = new File("C:/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you connect to database and run SQL by Java, post code you have tried ?

Comment: I don't understand, you're already looping over the filenames. Just replace/add a line inside the `if` that does the database check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont udnerstand your question. Looping the for loop? It seems that you want to check, for each item in listOfFiles, if the item exists in a database? If so, create a method that takes a string (filename) as a method and does the check. Then after printing the filename (true branch of your if statement) you can call the method

```
if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
{
    String fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    System.out.println(fileName);
    doesFileExistInDb(fileName);
}
```

Comment: I understand your notion. Can you show me the sample template for those?

Comment: @user2471591 here you got your template http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Answer (score 0):

Not clear with your question. As you are already looping through the fileList and have the file name, all that you need is a database look up to check if it exists in the DB.

Have a preparedStatement ready, and for each fileName lookup the DB.