# Check in database if it exists or not

Tags: java, database, file, jdbc, parameters

In the code below, I parsed all the filenames, then with it, I am trying to check
the database to see if it exists in it or not. What am I doing wrong below? If so, can you let me know?

Also in execute command, I get an error saying listofFiles cannot be resolved to variable.

```
public class FileGetName {
public String fileName;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("C");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
              } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
              }
            }
    }

    public void doesFileExistinDB(String fileName) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs= null;
        try {
            conn = DBConnect.getInstance().dbOracleConnect();    
            String sql= "select * from PO_Parent_List where" +
            " po_number in (fileName)";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            }
        }



    public void execute() {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
        {
            String fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(fileName);
            doesFileExistInDb(fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with the `ResultSet` returned by the query. Consider returning a boolean value on the `doesFileExistinDB` method to show if the entry exists/doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: `new File("C")` <-- I hope this is not meant to be Windows' C: drive?

Comment: Note: This is a follow up to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17027921/1639625) question, and I assume OP put the code from the answer into the wrong place... when is `execute` called anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You **need to pass** `listOfFiles` in `public void execute()` method like:

```
public void execute(File[] listOfFiles){

}
```

That is why you are getting compilation error as `listOfFiles` can not be resolved to variable.

Or **you need to declare the variable `listOfFiles` into the class level**.

**Edit:** (Not able to understand from where you are calling execute)

```
int i = 0;//Declare i to class level.
public void execute(File[] listOfFiles) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
        {
            String fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(fileName);
            doesFileExistInDb(fileName);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: because you didn't declare i inside execute method or neither in the class level.

Answer (score 0):

`listOfFiles` is specific to the `main()` method. To make it visible to other portions of your class, you must declare it as a instance variable, for example:

```
public class FileGetName {
    public String fileName;
    public File[] listOfFiles;
```

Your method `doesFileExistinDB()` should return `boolean` and test if `rs` returns one more results in order to make sure the file name is found. See [Java ResultSet how to check if there are any results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. Your fileName is not being passed in the query. You are basically hardcoding the String "fileName" instead of your fileName.
2. Consider returning a boolean value to show if the file exists or not (if the resultSet has at least 1 entry, your file exists):

Thus, your method becomes:

```
public boolean doesFileExistinDB(String fileName) {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs= null;
    try {
        conn = DBConnect.getInstance().dbOracleConnect();    
        String sql= "select * from PO_Parent_List where" +
        " po_number in (?)";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, fileName); 
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next) {
            //You have data!
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How would I do about doing number 2?

Comment: I appended it to my answer.

Comment: So then it should be public boolean doesFileExistinDB(String fileName) ?

Comment: It's your choice, but I recommend it. This way you can tell express outside the method whether you found that file or not.
I updated my answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

`listofFiles` is declared in your `main` not in your function `execute()`. You can pass an the `listofFiles` by adding an argument to your function.

```
public void execute(File[] listOfFiles){

}
```

But you will encounter others problem. In your `execute()`. When you're doing :

```
if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
```

The variable 'i' is not initialized, but I think you're refering to :

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
```

If you want to acces `i`, you will need call `execute` in you `for`. Your method execute should then look like :

```
public void execute(File[] listOfFiles, int i){

}
```

EDIT: Be sure to look at all the answers, your code need more modifications and many people have pointed some things you should change.